# how to make python modules accessible by root

Tags: command-line, bash, 18.04, scripts, python

I am running an /etc/init.d script that which contains a line to run a python file like so

```
python /home/my_user/some/file.py
```

Since my /etc/init.d is being ran with sudo, I have noticed that certain modules I imported for the file.py script aren't being loaded in. I switched to root and opened a python cli session and I couldn't import my modules, one being yaml. To fix this, would I have to pip install of my third party packages in root again or move them from my user's site packages to somewhere in a root directory? Would adding

```
/home/my-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

to my PATH from inside that /etc/init.d shell script be wise here?

I believe that would look something like this

```
export PATH=${PATH:+$PATH:}/home/my-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
```

If anyone could assist then I'd really appreciate it. New "ish" to Linux and would like to do everything in the most idiomatic way possible. Thanks!

Comment: The headache you're going to have is that you've done user-local python library installations.  You should have installed the packages you were after with `sudo pip install` rather than just using pip without sudo and thereby forcing it to use your user-local packages repositories.

Comment: I only have like 4 third party packages. All of the rest are local. I can just install again with that command I'd assume. Thanks

Comment: You cannot safely share your local library path in `root`, unfortunately.  It would be faster to just install those PyPI requirements to the system-wide repository unfortunately.